# Julia - run a script and keep the interpreter running

Tags: shell, julia, interpreter

I am running a Julia script, but would like to have the interpreter keep itself open after the script is executed.

E.g. when I run `julia example.jl`, I'd like the script to run and the interpreter to stay open after that, so I can experiment with the results.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alternatively, you can just use the `-i` (interactive) flag.  See `julia --help` for more details.

```
julia -i example.jl
```

Note, though, that the REPL won't start if the script errors.

Answer (score 7):

Open up the REPL from the shell with `julia` and run your code from there with:

```
include("example.jl")
```

This will execute your file from the REPL and will allow you play around with your results.